# Find value in multi dimensional array using PHP array_column

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, match

Good day, is it possible to find a value in a multi dimensional array using something like this:

```
$array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']];
$key = array_search('y', array_column($array , array_search('y', current($array))));
```

While I could use a `for()` loop to iterate through it and find the value but I am trying to see if there's a way to do this as a one liner.

So far i'm stuck on `array_search()` returning false, should only return an `int`

Comment: Your question is not clear, add some more explanations.

Comment: As it's a multidimensional array, this would need 2 numbers to identify the location (1,1 in this case), so how can you do this just with 1 value?

Comment: @jibsteroos apologies for copy past error

Comment: @NigelRen , very good point I'll tweak a bit and post an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_walk_recursive`

```
$array  = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']];
$findme = 'y';
$key    = null;
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use($findme, &$key){
  if($v === $findme) $key = $k;
});
echo $key;
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/GUqGH

---

In case if you need both keys use `array_walk`

```
 array_walk($array, function($v , $k) use (&$keys, $findme){
    $found = array_search($findme, $v);
    isset($found) ? ($keys = [$k, $found]) : '';
 }); 
 print_r($keys);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/U6bhn

Comment: extended my sub arrays to 6 and changed the position of y, your 2nd example only works if the needle you looking for is in the last sub array, busy trying to find a way to make it work regardless of the position of y

Comment: @JellyBean update the question with the input array

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you should be able to test with the array as is just change the needle / search variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach to search all the target value,

```
$search = "y";
$keys = [];
$array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']];
foreach($array as $row_index => $value){
    foreach($value as $col_index => $v){
        if($search == $v){
            $keys[] = array(
                "row_index" => $row_index,
                "col_index" => $row_index
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _While I could use a for() loop to iterate through it and find the value but I am trying to see if there's a way to do this as a **one liner**._

Comment: No matter which way you choose, it must traverse all the value.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` also iterate all the value. same as `array_column`, `array_search`

Comment: If the sought value is guaranteed to be unique or the asker only wants to find the key of the first encountered match, then a `break` will improve performance.  Further, if only one set of key is desired, then a multidimensional array is unnecessary.  The other functional style answers cannot `break` or `return` early.  So despite this answer defying the wishes of the asker, it provide some important features/benefits in readability, maintainability, and potentially performance.

Answer (score 0):

array_column retrieve whole array that match the key you have inserted. Here it seems you're trying to get the row and column index of the value.

You can do it like

```
$array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']];
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $array ); $i++ ){
    $key = array_search( 'y', $array[ $i ] );
    if( $key ) {
        echo "Row: ". $i . " Key: " . $key . "<br />";
    }
}
```

further implementation is up to your requirements.